# jQuery change() loops only adding last change() from object?

Tags: jquery, forms, object, for-loop, onchange

I have an array that has settings like so:

```html
["1", "open_order", "form", "county", "San Diego", "title_officer", "Peter", "0"]
["2", "open_order", "form", "county", "San Diego", "branch", "MV", "0"]
["3", "open_order", "form", "county", "San Diego", "title_officer", "Tom", "0"]
["4", "open_order", "form", "county", "San Bernardino", "branch", "RV", "0"]
```

It creates an array like so:

```js
$(function() {
  var o = [];
  var i = 0;
  var predata = $('#preferences').text();
  var data = JSON.parse(predata);
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var dataObject = {};
      dataObject['preferenceId'] = data[i][0];
      dataObject['pageName'] = data[i][1];
      dataObject['preferenceType'] = data[i][2];
      dataObject['baseField'] = data[i][3];
      dataObject['baseValue'] = data[i][4];
      dataObject['targetField'] = data[i][5];
      dataObject['targetValue'] = data[i][6];
      dataObject['conditionalId'] = data[i][7];
        o[i] = dataObject;
    }
    $.each(o, function() {
      console.log();
      var baseField = $('#' + o.baseField);
      var baseValue = o.baseValue;
      var targetField = $('#' + o.targetField);
      var targetValue = o.targetValue;
      
      baseField.change(function() {   
        if (baseField.val() == baseValue) {
          
            targetField.val(targetValue);
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Above, I am trying create a change event for every time the baseField.val() matches the baseValue. From here, this will update other select boxes/input fields.

However, the change() only works for the last object in the list.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Off the top of my head, try putting `var` before `i = 0` in the for loops: ` for(var i = 0; i < ....`

Comment: I believe part of the issue is all the baseFields are `country` so you are most likely creating duplicate bindings on that single country element on the page.  I'm also confused why you are doing `Object.keys(o).length` when `o` is an array and you can just do `o.length`  or change it from a for each into an `o.forEach()`

Comment: Negative :/ Thanks though! @ChrisHappy

Comment: @Taplar sooo... any suggestions?

Comment: I'd ask why you're creating duplicate bindings on a single element first.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hjkcafdg/  Also `var` variables are function scoped, not block scope, so their values at the end of the for loop will be whatever their last values were.  So while you are making duplicate bindings, all the bindings are processing with the last values that the variables had, which would have been set from the last for loop iteration.

Comment: @Taplar o is an object.

Comment: You're creating an object and making it's keys 0-n ? Why not use an array instead.

Comment: @Taplar good point. I updated it. will try foreach and see what happens.

Comment: @Taplar I updated to use the $.each() - any idea why it's not working now?

Comment: You'll want to pass `index, element` or two variables named whatever you like to the function in the each.  Then reference that element passed in on the arguments.  The `$.each()` api docs should show examples of this.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for your help with this! You lead me in the right direction. I posted an answer that has my final code in it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked.

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = [];
  var i = 0;
  var predata = $('#preferences').text();
  var data = JSON.parse(predata);
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var dataArr = {};
      dataArr['preferenceId'] = data[i][0];
      dataArr['pageName'] = data[i][1];
      dataArr['preferenceType'] = data[i][2];
      dataArr['baseField'] = data[i][3];
      dataArr['baseValue'] = data[i][4];
      dataArr['targetField'] = data[i][5];
      dataArr['targetValue'] = data[i][6];
      dataArr['conditionalId'] = data[i][7];
        arr[i] = dataArr;
    }

    $.each(arr, function(key, value) {
      var baseField = $('#' + value.baseField);
      var baseValue = value.baseValue;
      var targetField = $('#' + value.targetField);
      var targetValue = value.targetValue;
      
      baseField.change(function() {   
        if (baseField.val() == baseValue) {
          
            targetField.val(targetValue);
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Sure, but IMO `this` should be avoided as much as possible. It could seem like hairsplitting until you try to refactor this code. Taplar's suggestion is more robust.

Comment: @nrodic I guess I'm not sure how to implement Taplar's solution. Would anyone be able to post an edited version of the code?

Comment: $.each(o, function(**key, value**) { var baseField = $('#' + **value**.baseField... Again, your solution is perfectly valid.